# run same command for multiple file at the same time

Tags: shell-script, command-line, parallelism

I need to run same command separately for each file at the same time.

I've tried

```
for file in *.txt; do ./script <"$file"; done
```

but It starts the first one and waits until it get finished then goes to the next one.

I need to start them all together.

Comment: check out http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `script` doesn't require any input from the user, you could use the shell's job processing features to run it in the background

```
for file in *.txt; do ./script <"$file" & done
```

When you append `&` to a command it's run in the background. Look up *job control* in the man page for `bash` (or your preferred shell) for details.

Answer (score 3):

```
ls *.txt > list
cat list | parallel './script {}' &
wait
```

First list out the txt files in `list` file. `parallel` command will run the `script` on each file_name in background. Last `wait` command will wait for all the background jobs to finish then you can proceed for further commands.

Comment: What about `ls -d *.txt | parallel './script {}'`? I'm pretty sure you don't need to put `parallel` in the background only to `wait` for it.

Comment: [don't parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs): `printf "%s\n" *.txt | parallel './script {}'`

Comment: @glennjackman what's the difference in this situation between `ls -d *.txt` and `printf "%s\n" *.txt`? Both break on file names containing `\n`. Both depend on `parallel` to "do the right thing" with weird characters in the filenames.

Comment: You don't need `ls` or `printf` for this... `parallel` alone can do it.